# How to plot coordinates from 2 excel-columns with basemap (float-error)

Tags: python, excel, projection, matplotlib-basemap

I'm new to python and to this community. I have to plot a lot a lot of cities on a global map with Basemap in Python (Robinson projection). Coordinates are given in an excel-file with about 10 columns, in 2 columns (latitude and longitude).I managed to only select these 2 columns, but when I perform the projection, I get "TypeError: a float is required". This is my code:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf') 
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import xlrd
plt.close('all')
#%%
dirname=('C:\\Users\\Guido\\Documents\\Geologie\\Programmeren\\Scripts van mij\\Deftig\\')
filename='WUP2014-F12-Cities_Over_300K.xls'
xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile(dirname + filename)
dframe = xlsfile.parse("DATA")

urbpop = DataFrame(dframe)
lat = urbpop[['Unnamed: 6']]
lon = urbpop[['Unnamed: 7']]
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(zorder = 0)
lons,lats = m(list(lon), list(lat))
m.scatter(lons, lats, color ='red')
```

The problem arises in the following line:

```
lons,lats = m(list(lon), list(lat))
```

[This is a picture of the excel-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppy0l.jpg)

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try beating them into floats.

```
lons,lats = m([float(i) for i in lon], [float(i) for i in lat])
```

Disclaimer: I didn't try running this.

Comment: Still error . I know get the message "ValueError: could not convert string to float: Unnamed: 7".

Comment: I guess those strings can't be converted to floats. Print them out and see what they look like (they're probably not even numbers). I don't have access to your files, so I can't really help you much more than that.

Comment: I posted a picture in the question-text, if that can help?

Comment: I got it. I'v put "drframe = xlsfile.parse("DATA", skiprows = 16)", and now it works. Thanks for the help!